# Django annotate multiple objects based on multiple fields on a M2M relationship

Tags: django, annotations, many-to-many

I want to efficiently annotate Model `A` objects based on some fields on model `B` which has a plain many-to-many relationship (not using a through model) to `A`. A wrinkle is that I must find the oldest `B` for each `A` (using `B.created_timestamp`) but then populate using `B.name`. I want to use the ORM not raw SQL.

I tried this but it's not correct:

```
a_qs = A.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
ordered_qs = a_qs.order_by('-b__created_timestamp')
oldest_qs = Subquery(ordered_qs.values('b__name')[:1])
result = list(a_qs.annotate(name=oldest_qs))
```

This annotates every `A` with the same oldest name of `B` across all `B`s related to `A`, but I want the oldest `B` among associated `B`s for each `A`.

Comment: This is a very hard problem to solve. Do you need to complete `B` object or could you do with just some of it's fields?

Comment: You just need the name of the oldest `B` for each `A`?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: I found a hacky solution where I annotate both `B.created_timestamp` and `B.name` onto `A` and then essentially do the group-by in Python (b/c it returns a distinct result for each M2M relationship). I'd prefer to be able to do it with the ORM.

Comment: Do you have a through table defined? I think it would be possible if you did

Comment: No, this is a plain `ManyToManyField`. I'll update the description clarifying this point.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set `OuterRef` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/

```
b_qs = B.objects.filter(a=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_timestamp')
a_qs = A.objects.filter(id__in=ids).annotate(oldest_name=Subquery(b_qs.values('name')[:1])
result = list(a_qs)
```